# R: solving for a variable

Tags: r, equation-solving

I wonder if there's any function that can solve for a variable in an equation in terms of other values.

For example, I have:

```
(a-1/3)/(a+b-2/3)==0.3
```

The output of this function should be:

```
(0.3*b+0.1333333)/(0.7)
```

Or something along these lines.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Yacas* through the `Ryacas` package:

```
library(Ryacas)
a <- Sym("a")
b <- Sym("b")
Solve((a-1/3)/(a+b-2/3)==0.3, a)
# Yacas vector:
# [1] a == -((-0.3 * b - 0.1333333333)/0.7)
```

To get the solution as an expression, do:

```
solution <- Solve((a-1/3)/(a+b-2/3)==0.3, a)
yacas(paste0("a Where ", solution))
# expression(-((-0.3 * b - 0.1333333333)/0.7))
```

You can define a function returning the solution in function of `b` as follows:

```
f <- function(b) {}
body(f) <- yacas(paste0("a Where ", solution))$text
f
# function (x) 
# -((-0.3 * b - 0.1333333333)/0.7)
```

Also note that you do rational calculus to get exact values:

```
q1 <- Sym(1)/Sym(3)
q2 <- Sym(2)/Sym(3)
solution <- Solve((a-q1)/(a+b-q2)==0.3, a)
solution
# [1] a == -(3 * (-0.3 * b - 1.2/9)/2.1)
Simplify(solution)
# [1] a + (-0.9 * b/2.1 - 3.6/18.9) == 0
```